# How can I exec into a K8s pod but use a bash_profile from outside of it?

Tags: bash, kubernetes

My `.bash_profile` has many aliases that I use regularly. When I exec into a kubernetes pod, though, those aliases become (understandably) inaccessible. And when I say "exec into" I mean:

`kubectl exec -it [pod-name] -c [container-name] bash`

Is there any way to make it so that I can still use my bash profile after exec'ing in?

Comment: My first thought is to use kubectl copy to copy your local ~/.bashrc file to the pod first.   Special care may be required to not delete the current contents of the remote ~/.bashrc.

Comment: What about passing -l option to load /etc/profile ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said those are only the aliases. In that case and only in that case you could save the .`bash_profile` in the `ConfigMap` using `--from-env-file`

```
kubectl create configmap bash-profile --from-env-file=.bash_profile
```

Keep in mind that each line in the env file has to be in VAR=VAL format.

**Lines with # at the beginning and blank lines will be ignored.**

You can then load all the key-value pairs as container environment variables:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: bash-test-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "env" ]
      envFrom:
      - configMapRef:
          name: bash-profile
  restartPolicy: Never
```

Or [Populate a Volume with data stored in a ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#populate-a-volume-with-data-stored-in-a-configmap):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: bash-test-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "ls /etc/config/" ]
      volumeMounts:
      - name: config-volume
        mountPath: /root/.bash_profile
  volumes:
    - name: config-volume
      configMap:
        # Provide the name of the ConfigMap containing the files you want
        # to add to the container
        name: bash-profile
  restartPolicy: Never
```

The idea mentioned by @[Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2203038/mark) should also work.

If you do `kubectl cp .bash_profile <pod_name>:/root/` if you need to put it into a specific containers you can add option `-c, --container='': Container name. If omitted, the first container in the pod will be chosen`.